# What is proper etiquette for editing question titles and questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

I was about to edit the title of ["milgard vs jeld-wen"](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/milgard-vs-jeld-wen) (to something like "Which window brand is better, Milgard or Jeld-Wen?").  However, I don't yet have the 2000 rep normally required to edit others' questions (only [Eric](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/44/eric-petroelje) does); I only have the power to edit because I was appointed [moderator pro tempore](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/moderator-pro-tem-announcement).  Two questions:

- Are people OK with my editing questions and titles for clarity, or should I reserve my moderator powers for  bad behavior (until I gain 2000 rep)?
- In general, how eager should we be to edit other people's questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I think you should reserve moderator powers as much as possible and let the community handle issues like this.  But seeing that there is only one user with enough rep to edit titles AND this title is particularly poor, I say go for it.  I like the title you suggest too.

From [Robert Cartaino's](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/108/robert-cartaino) moderator email (referring to closing questions but the general message applies here too):

> you might give the community the chance to take
>   care of it. If the community won't (or
>   can't) act, do your thing. You have a
>   bit more leeway early on because few
>   people have the reputation to close.
>   And certainly take immediate action on
>   blatant problems (obvious spam,
>   illegal activities, language, etc).